# Help debugging an error in this program, please

Tags: java, debugging, linked-list, compiler-errors

I'm not sure if it's because I haven't slept or because I've never encountered it before, but I have no idea what this error means. I'm trying to compile a program that interacts with a doubly linked list using a custom object, and the compiler keeps telling me the following:

```
    19 errors found:
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 127]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:127: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 130]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:130: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 134]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:134: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 136]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:136: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 138]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:138: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 140]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:140: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 143]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:143: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 144]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:144: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 145]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:145: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 146]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:146: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 149]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:149: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 151]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:151: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 156]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:156: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 158]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:158: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 160]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:160: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 161]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:161: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 165]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:165: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 166]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:166: class, interface, or enum expected
File: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java  [line: 169]
Error: Z:\CS121\Project 6\prog6.java:169: class, interface, or enum expected
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


class prog6 {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    String tempName, keyName;
    Product tempProduct, temp;
    double tempPrice;
    boolean found;

    /* Here, add code to delcare and/or create a linked list
     and, if necessary, an iterator.
     */
    LinkedList<Product> list = new LinkedList<Product>();
    ListIterator<Product> iter = list.listIterator();

    //the following code reads product data from the file data.txt
    //and saves the product data in the linked list

    Scanner infile=new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));

    while(infile.hasNextLine())
    {
      tempProduct=tempProduct.addFirst(infile.nextLine(), infile.nextDouble());
      infile.nextLine(); //skip end-of-line

      /*here, add code to add the object tempProduct 
       to the beginning of the linked list*/

    }
    infile.close();

    while(true)
    {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();

      //show prompt messages and menu
      System.out.println("Please select one of the follwing actions:");
      System.out.println("q - Quit");
      System.out.println("a - print the product list");
      System.out.println("b - add a product");
      System.out.println("c - enter a product name to find the product record");
      System.out.println("d - delete a product");
      System.out.println("Please enter q, a, b, c, or d:");

      String selection=kb.nextLine();  //read user's selection
      if (selection.equals("")) continue; //if selection is "", show menu again

      switch (selection.charAt(0))
      {
        case 'q':
          System.out.println("Thank you");
          return;

          /*write code for the cases 'a','b','c' and 'd' */

        case 'a':
          temp = list;
          while (temp != null) 
          { 
            System.out.println (temp.data);
            temp = temp.next;
          }
          System.out.println();
          break;

        case 'b':
          System.out.println("Please enter the name of the new product:");
          tempName = kb.nextLine();
          System.out.println("Please enter the price of the new product:");
          tempPrice = kb.nextDouble();

          temp = new node(tempName, tempPrice);
          temp.next = list;
          list = temp;
          break;

        case 'c':
          System.out.println("Please enter a product name:");
          n=kb.nextLine();
          tempProduct = list.search(n);

          if(tempProduct == null)
            System.out.println("Cannot find product named " + n);
          else
            System.out.println("Product found: " + tempProduct);
          break;

        case 'd':
          System.out.println("Please enter name of a customer to remove from list:");
          tempString = kb.nextLine();
          list = delete(list, tempString);
          break;

        default: System.out.println("Incorrect selection.\n");
      } //end switch
    } //end while
  } //end main();

} //end class prog6


class Product
{
  String name;
  double price;

  public Product(String n, double p)
  { name=n;
    price=p;
  } //end Constructor

  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("%-20s%10.2f", name, price);
  }

} //end class Product

  public Product search (String key)
  {
    node temp = head;
    while (temp != null)
    {
      if (temp.data.name.equals(key))
        return temp.data;
      else
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void add (Product a)
  {
    node temp = new node (a);
    temp.next = head;
    head = temp;
  }
  public Boolean delete (String namekey, Product a)
  {
    node previous = null;
    node current = head;

    while (current != null)
    {
      if (current.name.equals(namekey))
      {
        current = current.next;
        if (previous == null)
          previous = current;
        else 
          previous.next = current;
        return true;
      }//end if
      else 
      {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
      }//end else
    }//end while
    return false;
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: By the way, I do realize that I haven't implemented every case correctly. I just wanted to see where I am. :/

Comment: line 127 is `  public Product search (String key)`

Comment: You have a long list of compiler errors, not bugs.  I suggest you only write a short program before you start seeing if it compiles. Ideally use an IDE as it will show you the errors as you type.  I suggest you start with the first error, which you don't list fix that, and more on to the next.  You refer to two classes you haven't provided.

Comment: @Lish, there are quite a few error before that line, I suggest you fix them first.

Comment: Where is `head` defined?

Comment: I'm not seeing any... shouldn't they be showing in the compiler?

Comment: I don't know but there are 9 errors reported by my compiler and I have checked they are correct. Sometimes errors are reported in the order it finds them and it may have been stuck on the errors on line 127 before it had chance to report the errors on 30, 65, 68, 69, 80, 81, 82, 98, 99.  This can happen because it can't make sense of the code which uses the Person class before it has compiled it.  I suggest you try breaking up your code into separate files and get each to compile in turn as you have clearly accumulated a mess here. (Which happens when you don't compiling as you go)

Comment: @peter I see. Well, to be fair, it's hard to compile as I go when most of the code was given by my professor and I just have to fill in the hard parts. I see what you're saying, though. I'll get to those once this other error is fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is at line

```
  public Product search (String key)
```

and the cause is that java accepts only class, interface or enum definitions at the top level (as the message quite clearly states).

Comment: Okay... It's probably my lack of sleep at this point, but I have no idea what that means either. Could you explain?

Comment: Ok, Lish, what are you defining there? What is "search" supposed to be?

Comment: search is supposed to be a method that searches for a product string inside the linked list and it should return a Product node.

Comment: @Lish: you can't define a method outside of a class (or enum).

Comment: @mark OOHHH. So I need to move the search/add/delete methods into the main class? That makes a bunch more sense. I feel kind of silly now. I figured it would be a simple issue. Guess I was right. :x Thanks

Comment: BTW, when we talk about syntax errors, it is absolutely irrelevant what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

The method:

```
public Product search (String key)
```

is defined outside your class.